# Manage paths with accented characters

Tags: batch-file, path, diacritics

In a batch, specifying a path whose name contains an accented character, files are not being found into the file System while 
stripping out all accented character in the path, these files are found. Nevertheless, 
I have to manage paths written with accented character. Is there any way to solve this issue?

If you need to know my OS, I'm on SEVEN 32.

Thanks

Comment: I have some path and file names with cyrillic chars and no issues with them. Can you post some examples? What editor do you use for batch programming? Can you deal with the file names in for loops, eg. `for %%i in (*) do echo(%%~i`?

Comment: editors which i use is either bloc-notes or notepad++.Here's the code that's written!
@echo off&setlocal
for /f "tokens=2* delims== " %%x in (Myfile) do (
    if /i "%%x"=="dir1" set "path1=%%y"
    if /i "%%x"=="dir2" set "path2=%%y"
)

echo %path1%
echo %path2%

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('findstr /v /C:" " Myfile') do (

echo "%path1%\%%x.txt"==========================================
Call second.bat "%path1%\%%x.txt")

Comment: once %path1% or %path2% contains an accented character, file is not found, so  Call second.bat "%path1%\%%x.txt") is faulty. If i delete aceented character into the path1 and path2, it's right. BUT I DON't want to.Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of these filnames in your question? I can easily create filenames with foreign letters (ė, â, Ú, ø) and deal with them by batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch by default configuration can't print unicode characters but CAN recognize that chars and use it.
That means you can't print "ú" but you can acces to a folder called "ú" or touch a file called "ú".

Then if your script fails to acces a file with accented characters maybe the reason is because the encoding of your script is not ANSI,
so open the script in notepad and ensure to save it with ANSI encoding (no utf-8 or unicode).

**Example:**

```
@echo off

CHCP 850 >NUL

for %%# in (*.txt) do (

    Echo [+] reading File: .\%%~nx# | MORE
    Type "%%~nx#"
) 

Pause>NUL
```

**Output:**

```
[+] reading File: .\áéíóúàèìòù ñ Ñ ç Ç.txt

This is the text content of my file with ISO-Latin characters
```

If you want to print accented characters in CMD then you need to make the char conversion, this can do the trick:

```
@echo off
CHCP 850 >NUL
copy con Mychars.txt
```

In that prompt you will write the characters you want, for example "**éíóú**", then you will get a "Mychars.txt" textfile with this content:

```
 ‚¡¢£
```

Now you can use that chars to print the accented chars:

```
@echo off
echo ‚¡¢£
Pause>NUL
```

**Output:**

```
éíóú
```

PS1: Remember to do all the things that I said saving the script in ANSI encoding.

PS2: Notice how I'm using CHCP 850 command, that means the codepage of the CMD, By default CMD uses the 850 codepage but I launch the CMD with a default 1250 codepage to avoid all those problems so in my examples I needed to use codepage 850 to show you.

You can set the default CMD Codepage with a registry key:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V "Autorun" /T "REG_SZ" /D "chcp 1250 >NUL" /F >NUL 2>&1
```

And you can read about the codepages here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195064.aspx

Comment: For now, I have just changed in Notepad's preferences UTF8 to ANSI, save the file, open it to look at if ANSI is currently by default encodage and close it. Nevertheless the script still fails to access the file through its path. Thanks

Comment: Is it normal or should i have to do the following you have suggested to only access the file?

Comment: I note that I don't have this problem in vbsscipt. indeed, files whose paths contain accented character  are found. What is not case in Windows batch.

Comment: GREAT! it's working fine now. you free me from a heavy charge. thanks you very much.

Comment: This didn't worked for me, the paths were still bad (accented chars were replaced by other chars) what I had to do is change de codepage to 1252.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Users\dmb3419\Documents\dev\ééééééééé"
```

This works:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
start "" "C:\Users\dmb3419\Documents\dev\ééééééééé"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with French accents in pathnames using a .bat and xcopy.

using:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
```

handled this for me and the accents were correctly recognised in the .bat file.
running under MS server2012 R2 cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Please, see below how your tip solved my problem without mixing it with alien code:

CHCP 1252
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "Z:\CYRO\ARTE\ArteRH Dicionário de Dados.xlsx"
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "Z:\CYRO\ARTE\Unificação\01 - MATERIAL APOIO\PADRAO_TABELA_CONVERSAO.xlsx"

Hope it can help somebody else!
Best regards.