# How do I create files/folders with diacritics using a bat script

Tags: batch-file, encoding, diacritics

I have a bat file that reads the lines a file, and then tries to create files or folders, depending on the given argument.

The problem is that when it gets to chars as ăâțîș, it does not work.

This is my code:

```
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Final
IF "%1"=="file" GOTO File
IF "%1"=="folder" GOTO Folder

:File
    for /f %%i in (files.txt) do echo. > %%i.rtf
GOTO Final

:Folder
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (folders.txt) do (
    mkdir "%%a"
    )
GOTO Final

:Final
```

What I've tried so far using this link: [Manage paths with accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180652/manage-paths-with-accented-characters)

1. The bat script is ANSI
2. CHCP 1250 > NUL

How can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manage paths with accented characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180652/manage-paths-with-accented-characters)

Comment: @wOxxOm, already check that link, didn't solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `CHCP XXX` into the batch where XXX is a codepage that matches encoding of your text files (files.txt and folders.txt). Note that you can use `CHCP 65001` which is equivalent of UTF-8 and should handle most of diactrics without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using accented characters in file and folder names. Otherwise, [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) warranted in windows command line.

```
md files   2>NUL
pushd files
md unASCII 2>NUL
chcp 852 >nul
echo ěščřžýáíé-852>diacritic--852.txt
chcp 1250 >nul
echo ěščřžýáíé1250>diacritic-1250.txt

chcp 1250 >nul
findstr /R "^" "diacritic-*.txt"
for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo %G:%g
for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo(%~nG:%g>"unASCII\%gANSI.txt"
chcp 852 >nul
findstr /R "^" "diacritic-*.txt"
for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo %G:%g
for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo(%~nG:%g>"unASCII\%g-OEM.txt"
popd
```

Note that above list of `CLI` commands isn't a `.bat` code snippet. However, copying & pasting it in a command line window gives roughly next **output** showing that code page actual when a file is *created* and *used* must chime in with each other. Otherwise, a crystalline *mojibake* visible, see e.g. `findstr /R "^" "diacritic-*.txt"`:

```
==>md files   2>NUL
==>pushd files
==>md unASCII 2>NUL

==>chcp 852 >nul
==>echo ěščřžýáíé-852>diacritic--852.txt

==>chcp 1250 >nul
==>echo ěščřžýáíé1250>diacritic-1250.txt

==>
==>chcp 1250 >nul

==>findstr /R "^" "diacritic-*.txt"
diacritic--852.txt:Řçźý§ě ˇ‚-852
diacritic-1250.txt:ěščřžýáíé1250

==>for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo %G:%g
diacritic--852.txt:Řçźý§ě ˇ‚-852
diacritic-1250.txt:ěščřžýáíé1250

==>for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo(%~nG:%g>"unASCII\%gANSI.txt"

==>chcp 852 >nul

==>findstr /R "^" "diacritic-*.txt"
diacritic--852.txt:ěščřžýáíé-852
diacritic-1250.txt:ýÜŔ°×řßÝÚ1250

==>for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo %G:%g
diacritic--852.txt:ěščřžýáíé-852
diacritic-1250.txt:ýÜŔ°×řßÝÚ1250

==>for %G in (diacritic*.txt) do @for /F %g in (%G) do @echo(%~nG:%g>"unASCII\%g-OEM.txt"

==>popd
```

We have written `ěščřžýáíé` string (followed with CHCP number) to next files:

- `ěščřžýáíé-852` string in the `files\diacritic--852.txt` file, and
- `ěščřžýáíé1250` string in the `files\diacritic-1250.txt` file.

Then, we used those strings to create files of the `<String><Chcp><CPID>.txt` name pattern, where

- `<String>` = `ěščřžýáíé` string with diacritics read from `diacritic-<Chcp>.txt` file;
- `<Chcp>` = `-852` or `1250`: code page which the `diacritic-<Chcp>.txt` file was written under;
- `<CPID>` = `-OEM` or `ANSI`: textual abbreviation of code page name which this file was written under (`852` and `1250`, respectively).

Lets try to *use* last four files: `Copy&Paste` following *code snippet* in a command line window again:

```
chcp 437 >nul
dir /B /S "files\unASCII\*.txt"
for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do @echo %G
findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt"

chcp 1250 >nul
for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do type "%G"
chcp 852 >nul
for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do type "%G"
```

**Output**: we could see *mojibake* again and again:

```
==>chcp 437 >nul

==>dir /B /S "files\unASCII\*.txt"
d:\bat\files\unASCII\ýÜŔ°×řßÝÚ1250-OEM.txt
d:\bat\files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé-852-OEM.txt
d:\bat\files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé1250ANSI.txt
d:\bat\files\unASCII\Řçźý§ě ˇ‚-852ANSI.txt

==>for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do @echo %G
files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé-852-OEM.txt
files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé1250ANSI.txt

==>findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt"

==>
==>chcp 1250 >nul

==>for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do type "%G"

==>type "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé-852-OEM.txt"
diacritic--852:Řçźý§ě ˇ‚-852

==>type "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé1250ANSI.txt"
diacritic-1250:ěščřžýáíé1250

==>chcp 852 >nul

==>for %G in (files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé*.txt) do type "%G"

==>type "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé-852-OEM.txt"
diacritic--852:ěščřžýáíé-852

==>type "files\unASCII\ěščřžýáíé1250ANSI.txt"
diacritic-1250:ýÜŔ°×řßÝÚ1250
```

**OOPS**, why there is no output from `findstr`? Let's use

```
chcp 1250 >nul
findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\*.txt"
chcp 852 >nul
findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\*.txt"
```

Output shows that `findstr` causes *mojibake* not only in *file **contents*** but in *file **names*** as well:

```
==>chcp 1250 >nul

==>findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\*.txt"
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\ŤsR›zr ˇ‚1250-OEM.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\escrzŤ˙­'-852-OEM.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\escrzŤ˙­'1250ANSI.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\RÎzŤäe?'-852ANSI.txt

==>chcp 852 >nul

==>findstr /S /R "^" "files\unASCII\*.txt"
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\ŹsRŤzráíé1250-OEM.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\escrzŹ ş'-852-OEM.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\escrzŹ ş'1250ANSI.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open files\unASCII\R╬zŹńeś?'-852ANSI.txt
```

FYI: nor neither `CHCP 65001` (`UTF-8`) could help... And as per [MSDN: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), Windows NTFS object names seem to be `UTF-16` encoded:

> On newer file systems, such as `NTFS`, `exFAT`, `UDFS`, and `FAT32`,
>   Windows stores the long file names on disk in *Unicode* ... the file
>   system treats path and file names as an opaque sequence of **WCHAR**s.

Moreover:

> The shell and the file system have different requirements. *It is
>   possible to create a path with the Windows API that the shell user
>   interface is not able to interpret properly*.