# Manipulate paths with accents in batch

Tags: batch-file, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I know this is a common problem, but I still can't figure it out.

I have the following batch script, reading paths and file names stored in text files, but I keep getting errors regarding misinterpreted accents.

```
@echo off
CHCP 1252
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (names.txt) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%j IN (paths.txt) DO (
        IF %%i==%%l (
            copy /-Y "%%j" %cd%
            ren "%%k" "%%l"."%%m"
        )
    )
)
```

I tried with and without the CHCP line, encoding each file in UTF-8, AINSI, DOS 850, but none of it worked.

Comment: A debugging hint: try `@echo ON` and prefix `CHCP` and all `FOR` with the `@` symbol to appear as `@CHCP` and `@FOR` but let `IF` and `copy` and `ren` in verbose mode without `@` to see what really happen. (maybe add `@echo %%i==%%l` just before `IF`)

Comment: I already saw everything before by removing `@echo off` but I still wasn't able to understand how this works. Let's say the file is "Détective" (French), it will read "DÚtective" from both files (names.txt and paths.txt), but won't be able to find the file later since the path will be corrupted.

Comment: Flagrant mojibake case. Read [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31713084/3439404). The `CHCP 1252` used should correspond with `ANSI` encoded files.

Comment: I get the global idea, but don't understand the solution. I tried `CHCP 65001` with `UTF-8` files and `CHCP 1252` with `ANSI` files but like you said, it didn't help. Could you please tell me the proper way to do this ? And please don't tell me to avoid using accented characters, there's got to be a way to use them...

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with `CHCP 65001`, `UTF-8` text files. Had to change the console font to Lucida Console.